# Gherkin dynamic data with multiple logins

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

How can I have dynamic data in the scenario's depending on the user login (CompanyID).

```
 Scenario Outline: Animal – Animal Details Accordion – Blank “Type” Field defaults to Dog in UI
     Given Main Application Starts
     When User Navigate to "AnimalEdit" Page
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.AnimalID" is equal to <CompanyID>
    #This AnimalID has to be dynamic as well depending on the CompanyID login
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.AnimalID" is equal to "3261565235"
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.SelectedAnimalTypeID" is equal to <AnimalType>
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.Animal.SpeciesID" is equal to "Company.DefaultSpeciedId"
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.Animal.PrimaryBreedID" is equal to <PrimaryBreedID>
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.Animal.SecondaryBreedID" is equal to <SecondaryBreedID>
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.Animal.AgeGroup" is equal to <AgeGroup>
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.AnimalPoint.ConditionID" is equal to <ConditionID>
     And Verify "AnimalDetails.AnimalPoint.BittenStatus" is equal to <BittenStatus>

Examples:
    | CompanyID | AnimalType  | SpeciesID | PrimaryBreedID  | SecondaryBreedID  | AgeGroup  | ConditionID | BittenStatus  |
    | 0909      | 10          | 1         | 1000            | 1858              | 3153      | 19938       | 2             |
```

Comment: Just to start, assuming it's not your root problem, you should be using Scenario Outline: instead of Scenario: and indent Examples to be nested under your scenario. If your issue goes beyond that please go into further details and share your step_definitions/source

Comment: The issue is the login function uses the companyID therefore AnimalType, SpeciesID, PrimaryBreedID and etc will have different values depending on the companyID, my question is how to I test for each of these values depending on the companyID

Comment: Why should the animal id equal the company id? They are not the same thing. Your scenario makes no sense mostly because it is focused on HOW you think your application works. What scenarios should talk about is WHAT an application does and WHY its important. What is the relationship between the user and the animal. All the detail about fields and values should be removed from the scenario, you can test those in step definitions or maybe unit tests.

Comment: I guess then you will have to integrate an API module to the tests and get the results from the companyID parsed and stored somewhere to compare with the gherkin steps